# Cant figuure out the control flow of my Javascript program

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple Javascript/Jquery program which will cycle through a product carousel I have on the front page of a website.

Here is the code:

```js
 jQuery(document).ready( function() {
  function next() {
   if(window.location.href === window.location.origin + '/') {
    var nextButton = jQuery('.prevSlide');
    nextButton.trigger('click');
    console.log('next');
    return;
   }
  }

  function prev() {
   if(window.location.href === window.location.origin + '/') {
    jQuery('.nextSlide').click();
    console.log('prev');
    return;
   }
  }

  jQuery('.iosSlider').hover( function() {
   jQuery(this).addClass('pauseInterval');
  }, function () {
   jQuery(this).removeClass('pauseInterval');
  }
  );

  function cycleNext() {
   if( !(jQuery('.prevSlide').hasClass('disabled'))) {
    if( !(jQuery('.iosSlider').hasClass('pauseInterval'))) {
     next();
    }
   } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    intervalTwo = setInterval(cyclePrev, 2000);
    console.log('interval cleared');
    console.log('intervalTwo set');
    return;
   }
  }

  function cyclePrev() {
   if( !(jQuery('.nextSlide').hasClass('disabled'))) {
    if(!(jQuery('.iosSlider').hasClass('pauseInterval'))) {
     prev();
    }
   } else {
    clearInterval(intervalTwo);
    var interval = setInterval(cycleNext, 2000);
    console.log('intervalTwo cleared');
    console.log('interval set');
    return;
   }
  }

             var interval = setInterval(cycleNext, 2000);
  console.log('interval set');

 });
```

In each of the next() and prev() functions, I check whether I am on the home page, and only proceed if so.

There is also some code there to pause the cycle if the mouse is hovering over the product slider.

When the slider is at the very start or end, a class called 'disabled' is added to the prevSldie and nextSlide anchors.

So ideally I want to click through to the end of the slider, and then click back to the start, then the end, etc.

So the control flow, as I understand it, is as follows:

An interval is set so that the next button on my carousel is clicked every two seconds.

The slider reaches the end, that interval ends and a new one is set.

The previous button is clicked every two seconds until the start of the carousel.

This process repeats infinitely.

Things run fine when the slider runs to the end, the start, and the end again, and then things go haywire.

Console output (should click next and prev 5 times each)

(5) next
interval cleared
intervalTwo set
(5) prev
intervalTwo Cleared
interval set
(5) next
interval cleared
intervalTwo set
interval cleared
intervalTwo set
prev
next
(2) prev
next
(2) prev
next

And it only gets more haywire all over the place from there.

I cant figure out why everything works fine for the first few loops and stops working after that, any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are your intervals scoped correctly? You never define intervalTwo, so it becomes a global. Then also in the cyclePrev function, you use var interval again, which will be scoped to this function and hence won't contain the interval outside the function, that you want to clear once cycleNext gets reached again. Try changing:

```
var interval = setInterval(cycleNext, 2000),
    intervalTwo = null;
console.log('interval set');
```

And then change `var interval = setInterval(cycleNext, 2000);` inside cyclePrev into `interval = setInterval(cycleNext, 2000);`

Comment: That was it! I knew it had to be something simple. I'm still getting used to the intricacies of Javascript :)